# multiplying by cell above to create pandas dataframe with formula

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get a new df column 'dos' that starts at 100, then each cell after that would multiply the number above it by the corresponding cell in 'uno'.  For some reason it's just giving me NaN after 100.

```
GrVsVal = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['uno', 'dos'], index = df_ch.index)
GrVsVal['uno'] = 1 + (df_ch['IVV'] - df_ch['IVE'])
GrVsVal['dos'].ix[0] = 100
GrVsVal['dos'].ix[1:] = GrVsVal['uno'].ix[1:] * GrVsVal['dos'].ix[0:]

print GrVsVal
```

it gives me:

```
          uno     dos
Date    
1/2/12   .997     100
1/3/12   .677     NaN
1/4/12   .986     NaN
```

so the first NaN should be  100 * .677,  the second NaN would be the result of the first NaN * .986

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
GrVsVal = pd.DataFrame({'uno': 1 + df_ch['IVV'] - df_ch['IVE']}, index = df_ch.index)

GrVsVal['dos'] = 100
GrVsVal.loc[1:, 'dos'] = GrVsVal.uno[1:].cumprod() * 100
>>> GrVsVal
          uno       dos
  Date
1/2/12  0.997  100.0000
1/3/12  0.677   67.7000
1/4/12  0.986   66.7522
```

Comment: Thank you my friend!  You have no idea how frustrated I was getting trying to figure this out ha!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to tell what some of the stuff is in your code. But this got  the results you wanted (if I'm understanding correctly):

```
import pandas as pd


date = ['1/2/12', '1/3/12', '1/4/12']
uno = [.997, .677, .986]

GrVsVal = pd.DataFrame({'date': date, 'uno':uno})
dos = [100]
i = 0
for u in GrVsVal.iterrows():
    while i+1 < len(GrVsVal['uno']):
        dos.append(GrVsVal['uno'][i+1]*dos[i])
        i += 1

GrVsVal['dos'] = dos

print(GrVsVal)
```

run that and you'll see the results. then adapt the code as needed.
EDIT: sorry I messed that up. should be fixed now.